# numpy complicated manipulation of matrix multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, tensor

I want to multiply a 3D tensor with a 2D tensor and get a 2D tensor as result. The way I envision this to be done is rather strange, so I ask for your help.

The 3D tensor, for when we fix the value of the first dimension to some integer within `range(3D_tensor.shape[0])`, is a 2D matrix. We picture this 2D matrix as:

```
``[[a0, b0, c0], [d0, e0, f0], [g0, h0, p0]]``
```

I want this to be multiplied by the 2D tensor (see above) which can be pictured as:

```
 ``[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]``
```

The multiplication shall not be a matrix-matrix multiplication, but each row from the (left ) 2D matrix to be multiplied, element wise, with the corresponding row from the 2D tensor.
The result shall be a 3 element array:

```
``[a0 * 10 + b0 * 20 + c0 * 30,  d0 * 40, e0 * 50, f0 * 60, g0 * 70 + h0 * 80 + p0 * 90]``.
```

This multiplication procedure repeats for all the other "slices" of the 3D tensor. That is, if the 2D matrix picture above was for `3D_tensor[0, :, :]`, then we would have

```
``[[a1, b1, c1], [d1, e1, f1] ,[g1, h1, p1]]``
```

for `3D_tensor[1, :, :]`, and the result shall be

```
``[a1 * 10 + b1 * 20 + c1 * 30, d1 * 40 + e1 * 50 + f1 * 60, g1 * 70 + h1 * 80 + p1 * 90]``.
```

These 3-element 1D arrays shall be glued together into a bigger 2D array (the result I want to obtain), where each 3-element 1D array to be one of the 2D array's rows (so place them horizontally).
That would be, my final result in the pictures above, is a 2D array:

```
``[ [a0 * 10 + b0 * 20 + c0 * 30,  d0 * 40, e0 * 50, f0 * 60, g0 * 70 + h0 * 80 + p0 * 90], [a1 * 10 + b1 * 20 + c1 * 30, d1 * 40 + e1 * 50 + f1 * 60, g1 * 70 + h1 * 80 + p1 * 90] ] ``
```

Ideally, I want this to be done with the `BLAS` routines, but using `numpy`. Is what I want to obtain possible?

I know about np.dot, multiply, @, ... , and tried to use them, but I cannot figure how I can do the above, EFFICIENTLY, myself.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to reformat your question to make the arrays standout and easier to read.  I'm used to seeing arrays as `numpy` displays them; it's easier to grasp key properties like shape and dtype.  When asking about EFFICIENCY, it's a good idea to provide a working example that isn't 'efficienty' - arrays that are small but sufficiently general, and code (even it is iterative) that does what you want.  That way we can test improvements without fear of any ambiguities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import numpy as np

tensor3d = np.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3))
tensor2d = np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]])

res = (tensor3d * tensor2d).sum(2)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[  80  620 1700]
 [ 620 1970 3860]
 [1160 3320 6020]]
```

The expression:

```
tensor3d * tensor2d
```

returns:

```
[[[   0   20   60]
  [ 120  200  300]
  [ 420  560  720]]

 [[  90  200  330]
  [ 480  650  840]
  [1050 1280 1530]]

 [[ 180  380  600]
  [ 840 1100 1380]
  [1680 2000 2340]]]
```

basically element-wise multiplication, as requested. Then:

```
.sum(2)
```

sums the results across the third axis (2 for 0 based indexing). For example, for the first row of the final result:

```
80    = 0 + 20 + 60 
620   = 120 + 200 + 300
1700  = 420 + 560 + 720
```

**UPDATE**

To do the above operation for multiple arrays do:

```
import numpy as np

tensor3d = np.array([np.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3)), np.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3))])
tensor2d = np.array([np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]),
                     np.array([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]])])

tensor2d = tensor2d[:, np.newaxis, ...]

res = (tensor3d * tensor2d).sum(3)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[[  80  620 1700]
  [ 620 1970 3860]
  [1160 3320 6020]]

 [[  80  620 1700]
  [ 620 1970 3860]
  [1160 3320 6020]]]
```

In this example:

```
tensor3d.shape = (2, 3, 3, 3)  # two 3d tensors
tensor2d.shape = (2, 1, 3, 3)  # two 2d matrices
res.shape = (2, 3, 3) # two 2d matrices
```

note that the original shape of `tensor2d` is `(2, 3, 3)` but in order for [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to work you need to add an extra dimension, hence the expression:

```
tensor2d = tensor2d[:, np.newaxis, ...]
```

Comment: thank you! do you know how could I adapt this to when ``tensor2d`` is a 3D tensor and the final result shall be a 3D tensor as well? [``tensor3d`` shall now be 4D, accordingly]  the new dimension size (so ``tensor2d.shape[0]``) is not necessarily equal to any other dimensions' sizes (``tensor2d.shape[1]`` or ``tensor2d.shape[2]``).

Comment: basically I would like to do what your answer does, but repeated a number of times ``N`` (number given by the new dimension's size), and stack the obtained ``N`` results  vertically out of the page in the resulting (now 3Dimensional) tensor.

Comment: So each 3dtensor in the new 4d tensor is multply by all the other 2 tensors?

Comment: each 3dtensor (say the 7th one, i.e. ``new_4dtensor[6, :, :, :]``) in the new 4dtensor shall be multiplied (in between commas, not a multiplication, but what your answer does) by only one 2d tensor (the one corresponding to the 7th 3d tensor, i.e. ``new_3dtensor[6, :, :]``), and the result shall be placed in ``final_result[6, :, :]``. this shall be repeated for all values of the first dimension index (not only 6, as in my example), basically efficiently populating the ``final_result`` 3D array

Comment: where by efficiently I mean without to use a for-loop (``for i in range(final_result.shape[0]``)

Comment: @velenos14 see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is largely a repeat of Dani's answer, but I just want to confirm my understanding of your question.

Making a more concrete version of your 3d array:

```
In [340]: A = np.arange(2*3*3).reshape(2,3,3); B = np.arange(10,100,10).reshape(3,3)
In [341]: A
Out[341]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
In [342]: B
Out[342]: 
array([[10, 20, 30],
       [40, 50, 60],
       [70, 80, 90]])
In [343]: (A*B).shape
Out[343]: (2, 3, 3)
```

It looks like you just want to multiply the 2 arrays, taking advantage of `broadcasting`, and sum along the last dimension (across columns):

```
In [344]: (A*B).sum(axis=2)    # axis=-1 for last
Out[344]: 
array([[  80,  620, 1700],
       [ 620, 1970, 3860]])
```

So for one plane of `A` and one row:

```
In [345]: (A[0,0,:]*B[0]).sum()
Out[345]: 80
```

In general if `A` is (N,3,3) and `B` is (3,3), then `A*B` is also (N,3,3), and the `sum` reduces it on the last dimension, producing a (N,3) result.

This can also be expressed as a matrix product with `einsum`:

```
In [352]: np.einsum('ijk,jk->ij',A,B)
Out[352]: 
array([[  80,  620, 1700],
       [ 620, 1970, 3860]])
```

`matmul/@` can also do it, but getting mix of dimensions right is trickier.

If `A` is (N,M,3,3) and `B` is (M,3,3), `A*B.sum(axis=-1)` produces (N,M,3).

In `broadcasting` the `B` is expanded to (1,M,3,3) and then to (N,M,3,3) to match `A`.